# google smart home actions with lambda function

Tags: google-smart-home

I want to implement google smart home actions with lambda functions?
I use below example to implement
https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/smarthome-washer/#0

I can run this sample with Firebase function, but now I want to implement 
with lambda function, how to do this, any reference or SOP I can follow?

BR,
Jack

Answer (score 0):

The codelab uses the [Actions on Google library](https://github.com/actions-on-google/actions-on-google-nodejs), which should have easy support for [AWS Lambda API Gateway](https://github.com/actions-on-google/actions-on-google-nodejs#aws-lambda-api-gateway):

```
// ... app code here

exports.fulfillment = app
```